# Adding regular expression find option to UITextView

Tags: uikit, uitextview

I'm trying to implement a regular expression search in a `UITextView` with the `UITextView.findInteraction` introduced in iOS 16. The documentation shows a `UIFindInteraction.optionsMenuProvider` property and reads

> You use this closure to modify, augement or omit options from the
> default set available in UITextSearchOptions.

But it's not clear how to actually modify the `UITextSearchOptions`, and where these options are even stored. And how would I omit options? How can the `UIAction`s passed as the only argument to `UIFindInteraction.optionsMenuProvider` be distinguished from one another?